# overflow-x not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm about 25% done my website and I put everything in a .container

```
   html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    overflow-x: scroll;


}

.container {
    width: 1920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    background-image:url("/images/backgroundimg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: fixed;
    height: 773px;
}
```

Now i want to have a horizontal scroll bar when the window is smaller, i tried scroll and auto, the horizontal bar works when window is small but when its full screen it still shows the scroll bar and when i move it over its like 1px of random white space. Does anyone have a clue how to fix? (When full screen i want it gone, when minimized i want it to show)

Comment: Please provide a full usable code example. At least your HTML code is missing.

Answer (score 0):

change `overflow-x: scroll;` to `overflow-x: auto;`

Comment: Just noticed its something with my header img, if i make it smaller the scroll bar leaves, but then i get white spaces on either sides. I need to have this 100%. when i try width: !00% i get scroll bars

Comment: add overflow: hidden; on the header.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle to replicate the problem?